# Does Craft have a styleguide for the admin, like Bootstrap?

Tags: plugin-development, admin

Does Craft have a styleguide for the admin, like Bootstrap? I'd like to know how to create plugin interfaces that match with Craft

Answer (score 3):

Already found the answer, it seems it has a js lib called Garnish for UI interaction, and some grid system. Both are undocumented as of yet.